# How do I strip spaces & special characters from a string in specific positions? - Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

Say I have a string like this:

`May 12 -`

Where what I want to end up with is:

`May 12`

I tried doing a `gsub(/\s+\W/, '')` and that works to strip out the trailing space and the last hyphen.

But I am not sure how I remove the first space before the `M`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

**Use `match` instead of `gsub`** (i.e. extract the relevant string, instead of trying to strip irrelevant parts), using the regex `/\w+(?:\W+\w+)*/`:

```
" May 12 - ".match(/\w+(?:\W+\w+)*/).to_s # => "May 12"
```

Note that this is vastly more efficient than using `gsub` – pitting my `match` regex against [the suggested `gsub` regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10765386/990363), I get these benchmarks (on 5 million repetitions):

```
                      user     system      total        real
match:           19.520000   0.060000  19.580000 ( 22.046307)
gsub:            31.830000   0.120000  31.950000 ( 35.781152)
```

Adding a `gstrip!` step [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764292/990363) does not significantly change this:

```
                      user     system      total        real
match:           19.390000   0.060000  19.450000 ( 20.537461)
gsub.strip!:     30.800000   0.110000  30.910000 ( 34.140044)
```

Answer (score 1):

use .strip! on your result .

```
" May 12".strip!  # => "May 12"
```

Comment: So do `.strip!` & `gsub`? That seems a bit inefficient, no?

Comment: @marcamillion: no need to do both operations if you are using a regex already – `match` is your friend. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10765262/990363).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
/^\s+|\s+\W+$/
```

**explanation:**

```
/         : regex delim
^         : begining of string
  \s+     : 1 or more spaces
  |       : OR
  \s+\W+  : 1 or more spaces followed by 1 or more non word char
$         : end of string
/         : regex delim
```